# How to Firebase User Metadata in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase to store data from my `flutter` app and `Laravel` as my backend. I could retrieve all registered users from firebase to laravel using `kreait/firebase-php` package as follows.

[image: user data]

So I wanted to print metadata in my `laraval blade` and I'm getting error.

My Laravel `Firebasecontroller` as follows

```
public function authUsers(){
    $auth_users = $this->firebaseConnect()->getAuth();
    $users = $auth_users->listUsers();

    return view('Firebase.users', compact('users'));
}
```

My blade file as follows

```
<tbody>
    @php
        $no = 1;
    @endphp
    @foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->uid}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->disabled}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($user->metadata as $meta)
                {{$meta->createdAt}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

I'm getting below error

> Cannot use object of type DateTimeImmutable as array (View: /var/www/html/bec_mis/laravel/resources/views/Firebase/users.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use all the methods of the [`DateTimeImmutable` class](https://www.php.net/DateTimeImmutable) within blade templates, including the [`format()` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php). This (as an example) should work:

```
{{$meta->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}}
```

Comment: Still I'm getting error `Undefined property: DateTimeImmutable::$createdAt`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

`{{$user->metadata->createdAt->format('Y-m-d  H:i:s')}}`